# how log likelihood's derivative is equal to zero in maximum log likelihood.

Tags: probability, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, logistic-regression, log-likelihood

if the log-likelihood function is strictly increasing and it has not horizontal asymptote then how it's derivative is equal to zero in maximum log likelihood. Now since it is strictly increasing every time the parameters will tend to infinity. So why not take infinity as parameters directly.

Comment: log is strictly increasing, but the likelihood function need not be an increasing function, meaning there are numbers $x<y$ where the likelihood function, say $\ell$, applied to these numbers is $\ell (x) > \ell (y)$.  Then the log-likelihood, say $L$, for these numbers is $L(x) > L(y)$ even though $x<y$.

Comment: If the log-likelihood is strictly increasing then its maximum and the likelihood's maximum occurs at the right hand end; if that is at infinity then there is no maximum

Comment: So this means that the log is strictly increasing but log-likelihood is not. Am I correct?